# Assignment in a map function?

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```js
this.array1 = this.array1.map(a => (a.name = "Harold"));
```

The syntax is wrong and I’m unsure why. What I’m trying to do is: For every object in `array1`, I want `"name"` to be `Harold`.

The array is structured similar to this:

```js
array1 = [
    {
        name: "ashley",
        last: "bob"
    },
    {
        name: "tiny",
        last: "tot"
    }
]
```

The error I get is:

> Arrow function should not return assignment

The results I want is an array that is like:

```js
array1 = [
    {
        name: "Harold",
        last: "bob"
    },
    {
        name: "Harold",
        last: "tot"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is wrong? are there any errors? please add the expected and current output.

Comment: @ISAE I have edited my post! Thanks

Comment: remove the semicolon inside the Parenthesis after "Harold". also the second object in the array has `name =` instead of `name:`

Comment: `.map()` replaces each element in the array with the value returned by the callback function. Don't use map if you try to modify the objects objects themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spread the object and add another name for all object.

This method does not mutate the given data.

```js
const
     array1 = [{ name: "ashley", last: "bob" }, { name: "tiny", last: "tot" }],
     array2 = array1.map(object => ({ ...object, name: "Harold" }));

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Arrow function should not return assignment**

If you write your [arrow function] like below you are implicitly return whatever is inside the brackets. In this case it is an assignment. See the first demo on this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
this.array1 = this.array1.map(a => (a.name = "Harold"));
```

How map works is you have to return the object you want as an element in your Array. Below i am explicitly returning a.

```
this.array1 = this.array1.map(a => {
a.name = "Harold";
return a;});
```

Remember, you <strike>could have used</strike> should use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) here <strike>too</strike>. From the documentation, **map creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array**.

Comment: Exactly why I mentioned you could have used forEach too.

Comment: Forgot about forEach, thanks for the reminder and help!

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array taking as input the original array and returning in the callback the replacement of each item in the array.

You are not returning anything in your callback, you are just assigning a value, you could use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and return the same object already mutated:

```js
this.array1 = this.array1.map(a => (a.name = "Harold", a));
```

Snippet:

```js
const array1 = [{name: "ashley", last: "bob"}, {name: "tiny", last: "tot"}];

const array2 = array1.map(a => (a.name = "Harold", a));

console.log(array2);
```

> Note: As others pointed out, you should not use `map` to mutate the original array. Either you should use a `forEach` to mutate the objects or you should return a new array without mutating the original one. What happens with your solution (and this small edition that I proposed) is that you end up with a second array containing the same mutated objects of the first array.